# Cleaning up a SQL SP with Regex

Tags: sql, regex

1. If I am running a find and replace in SQL 2005 - what would be the regular 
   expression to find tab and space sequences ( or space and tab sequences ) 
   and replace them with just tab?
2. If I have a line which begins with a space - is there a regular expression 
   to convert that leading space to a tab?
3. What would be the regular expression to remove all of the spaces before a 
   CR/LF in a SQL statement?

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about the Quick Replace dialog in SQL Server Management Studio then this gets any combination of two or more spaces and/or tabs.

```
:b:b+
```

This finds all leading spaces/tabs (remove the `+` if you only want to match a single one)

```
^:b+
```

And this gets you all trailing spaces/tabs

```
:b+$
```

Stick `\t` in the *Replace with:* box to convert matches to a single tab.

Answer (score 0):

**Question 1**

```
UPDATE Customers SET Title = Replace(Title, '\t ', '\t') AND Title = Replace(Title, ' \t', '\t');
```

Taken From: http://www.sqlbook.com/SQL/SQL-Replace-Function-25.aspx

See if that solves your problem.. Ive never tried it though

You might have to perform 2 queries if the AND operator dont work :D

Answer (score 0):

found something at [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/tips/Regular_Expressions.aspx):

```
^[ \t]+|[ \t]+$
```

hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Of course do not type in the ' in the examples below:

Spaces before a CRLF - in SQL management Studio

find what: ' \n' replace with: '\n' check use: regular expressions

> How do you specify 1 or more spaces?

Spaces before a TAB

find what: ' \t' replace with: '\t' check use: regular expressions

> How do you specify 1 or more spaces?

Spaces after a TAB

find what: '\t ' replace with: '\t' check use: regular expressions

> How do you specify 1 or more spaces?

Empty Lines - TABs and CRLF

find what: '\t\n' replace with: '\n' check use: regular expressions

> How do you specify 1 or more tabs?